# Magento categories in orders list

Tags: magento, adminhtml

I want to show some additional data in sales grid view and be able to filter on it

I'm trying to show for each order the SKUs, Product Names, Total quantity and Product Manufacturers (or categories or another attribute)

With this code I'm able to get the first three

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
$collection
  ->join(
    array('s'=>'sales/order_item'),
    '`main_table`.entity_id=s.order_id',
    array(
    'skus'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(s.sku SEPARATOR ", ")'),
    'names' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(s.name SEPARATOR ", ")'),
    'items' => new Zend_Db_Expr('count(s.qty_ordered)'),
     )
    );
$collection->getSelect()->group('entity_id');
```

And it works :)

To get the additional data (es: locality, a custom attribute of product) I've to do another join to get product data so I suppose that my code should be something similar to

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
$collection
  ->join(
    array('s'=>'sales/order_item'),
    '`main_table`.entity_id=s.order_id',
    array(
    'skus'  => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(s.sku SEPARATOR ", ")'),
    'names' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(s.name SEPARATOR ", ")'),
    'items' => new Zend_Db_Expr('count(s.qty_ordered)'),
     )
    );
$collection //OR $collection->getSelect() both don't work
  ->join(
    array('p'=>'catalog/product'),
    'p.entity_id=s.product_id',
    array(
       .....
      )
    );

.... more stuff

$collection->getSelect()->group('entity_id');
```

But every time I try to add the second join I get a template o_O error in log

2013-10-03T14:27:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): Failed to load template:[MYBASEDIR]/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml

2013-10-03T14:27:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): Failed to load template:[MYBASEDIR]/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml

I'm really clueless... how to fix this ? how to do more than 1 join in that collection... ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `$collection->getSelect()->join(..);` rather than just `$collection->join(...);` if you wish to use it more than once.

Comment: as stated in the text I've tried also ->getSelect() but it doesn't work